# Using asynchronous methods but Express still returning 503 (NodeJS)

Tags: express, asynchronous, networking

I'm developing a web application in NodeJS with an Express back-end. The application is running smoothly except that when a user signs up, a somewhat long operation is called on the back end that involves saving to a database, resizing an image, etc. It takes a few seconds for this process to complete, and during this time anyone else who makes a request to the server will receive a 503 error and will be unable to do anything, whether that's sending or receiving data. I am using asynchronous functions in order to do this whole process. I am using multer to read the file, fs to read and write the file, and Jimp to resize the image. The code is as shown below.

```
module.exports = function(router) {
router.route('/')
    .post(function(req, res, next) {
        upload(req, res, function(err) {
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
            var identifier = makeIdentifier(req.body.first_name.trim())
            let emailNotifications = 0;
            if (req.body.email_notifications === 'true') {
                emailNotifications = 1;
            }
            var signup = {
                identifier: identifier,
                first_name: toTitleCase(req.body.first_name.trim()),
                last_name: req.body.last_name.trim(),
                hobby: req.body.hobby,
                type: 'user',
                email: req.body.email.trim(),
                email_notifications: emailNotifications,
                password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt)
            };

            let ascii = /^[ -~]+$/;

            for (var propertyName in signup) {
                if (!ascii.test(signup[propertyName])) {
                    res.json({
                        reason: "invalid-characters"
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (req.file.size > 5000000) {
                res.json({
                    reason: "file-size"
                });
                return;
            }
            let emailExists = false;
            db.doesEmailExist(req.body.email, function(err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send("Server error");
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        res.json({
                            reason: "email-exists"
                        });
                        return;
                    } else {
                        fs.readFile(req.file.path, function(err, data) {
                            let newPath = __dirname + "/profile-pictures/" + identifier + ".png";
                            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                } else {
                                    try {
                                        Jimp.read(newPath, (err, file) => {
                                            if (err) throw err;
                                            file
                                                .resize(300, 300) // resize
                                                .quality(60) // set JPEG quality
                                                .write(newPath); // save
                                        });
                                    } catch (error) {
                                        res.json({
                                            reason: "image-properties"
                                        });
                                        return
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        db.signup(signup, function(err, results) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.status(500).send("Server error");
                                return;
                            } else {
                                res.json({
                                    success: true
                                });
                                return;
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    });
}
```

What is causing the server to respond with a 503 error? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Wow, if there was ever a poster child for when to get rid of callback hell and use promises,, this would be it.

Comment: Get rid of all the `if (err) throw err;` and replace them with something that sends an error response.

Comment: Make sure every possible error path finishes the request and sends an error response.  For example, `if (err) { console.log(err);}` needs to send an error response and return.

Comment: In `upload(req, res, function(err) { ...}`, you have no error handling for when `err` is set.

Comment: @jfriend00 Haha, yeah this code isn't the cleanest for sure. I guess I could use async.series but this shouldn't have an effect on the way that the program runs, correct? Thanks for the pointers, but do you see anything that would cause the entire program to be held up as a result of this code?

Comment: If you end up with too many open connections that got some type of error and did not send a response, then it may take a long time for them to eventually time out.  In the browser, the browser will only ever send a small number of requests to a given host at once (queuing the others until one retrurns) so once you get that many requests waiting for an error, the browser won't send any more.  First step, fix ALL error handling to be sure you never leave a request hanging.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `async.series()`.  If you're going to invest in a clean-up, switch all your async operations to be promise driven and then you can implement much cleaner flow and error control using promise chaining.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Why not async series?

Comment: When you have complex asynchronous code, promises are a lot, lot easier to manage the flow and error handling than regular callbacks, even with the async library.  Promises are the future of the language for async code.  You could also probably really simplify your code using `await` too.